# Calling SOAP Webservice using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services, soap

I'm searching for a (javascript or jQuery) script which can call a external .asmx webservice which displays a simple selection of homes for sale. They say I'm able to filter out the selection belonging to a certain company using 'getAanbodByCorpID', but I'm very stuck.

The only thing I have is the URL of the external /Service.asmx and the corp id(=180).

Calling the Service.asmx?wsdl returns the wdsl webservice (?).

I guess my page needs to:

1. call the webservice
2. writes the filtered data into html

Can someone shed a light, please?

Comment: Have you tried using the jquery function $.ajax. You can use that to make asynchronous requests to any web service using javascript.

Comment: Can you give an example in how to use a variable in order to filter the selection?

Comment: You will probably want to use something like jQUery Soap plug-in to handle SOAP request/repsonse evelope formatting for you.  https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap

Comment: From the wsdl you can figure out the soap request and make an XHR accordingly.  Most soap webservices don't have CORS enabled and so I doubt you will be able to call it directly from the webpage using javascript.  You will likely need to to do the request from the server side (and there are lots of server side SOAP libraries).

Comment: @DMoses you were right: I receive an error: missing CORS-header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’. You said there are lots of server side SOAP libraries. Does this mean I have to develop something myself? Do you maybe have an example of this? It's hosted on (and I have remote acces to) a windows server.

Comment: @KestonPollard If you are using .net I suggest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx  If you are using Java I suggest http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html  I'm less familiar with node, perl, php, etc.  But they all have tools to generate clients from the wsdl.